# Identifying mismatched columns when comparing two rows that should be identical

Tags: r

I am comparing two data frames that have the same information, but were input by different people. If there are any mistakes I need to go back to the physicals record and verify what is the correct answer.

My objective is to identify the columns that mismatch for the rows that have the same ID. Then have a data frame that gives me the row ID and the columns that mismatch for that ID. This would make the job a lot easier when going back to the physical documents. I have cleaned up the data and now have only the rows that I know have inconsistencies. If you would like to know how I did this I used the dupsBetweenGroups function found here: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Comparing_data_frames/

I am putting an example below of the situation I am dealing with:

```
df1 <- data.frame(c("T-A1-1", "T-A1-2", "T-A1-3", "T-A1-4"), rep("AAA", 4), c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No"), c("", "family present", "present", ""), c(NA, NA, "hey", "hey"), as.Date(c("1jan2017", "2jan2017", "31mar2017", "30jul2017"), "%d%b%Y"), c(0, 2, 3, 4))
names(df1) <- c("ID", "Coder", "y/n", "string","NAs", "Dates", "num")

      ID Coder y/n         string  NAs      Dates num
1 T-A1-1   AAA Yes                <NA> 2017-01-01   0
2 T-A1-2   AAA  No family present <NA> 2017-01-02   2
3 T-A1-3   AAA Yes        present  hey 2017-03-31   3
4 T-A1-4   AAA  No                 hey 2017-07-30   4

df2 <- data.frame(c("T-A1-1", "T-A1-2", "T-A1-3", "T-A1-4"), rep("BBB", 4), c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No"), c("", "family is present", "present", "random"), c(NA, "hey", NA, "hey"), as.Date(c("1jan2017", "3jan2017", "31mar2017", "29jul2017"), "%d%b%Y"), c(1, 2, 5, 6))
names(df2) <- c("ID", "Coder", "y/n", "string","NAs", "Dates", "num")

      ID Coder y/n            string  NAs      Dates num
1 T-A1-1   BBB Yes                   <NA> 2017-01-01   1
2 T-A1-2   BBB Yes family is present  hey 2017-01-03   2
3 T-A1-3   BBB  No           present <NA> 2017-03-31   5
4 T-A1-4   BBB  No            random  hey 2017-07-29   6
```

Due to how I cleaned the data, both data frames are rbinded and organized by ID. Nonetheless each data frame has a `coder` column that allows me to see where the row originally came from (this also makes separating both data frames easier if I need to do that). The `coder` Column do not need to be compared. Same ID rows will have different values since they came from two different data frames. This said, the data frame with which I am starting off looks a little more like this:

```
dfboth <- rbind(df1, df2)
dfboth <- both[with(both, order(ID)), ]

      ID Coder y/n            string  NAs      Dates num
1 T-A1-1   AAA Yes                   <NA> 2017-01-01   0
5 T-A1-1   BBB Yes                   <NA> 2017-01-01   1
2 T-A1-2   AAA  No    family present <NA> 2017-01-02   2
6 T-A1-2   BBB Yes family is present  hey 2017-01-03   2
3 T-A1-3   AAA Yes           present  hey 2017-03-31   3
7 T-A1-3   BBB  No           present <NA> 2017-03-31   5
4 T-A1-4   AAA  No                    hey 2017-07-30   4
8 T-A1-4   BBB  No            random  hey 2017-07-29   6
```

The ideal situation would be to obtain a data frame that tells me the row ID and the columns they mismatch. Something similar to this (NOTE: I'm flexible on how the results will be displayed, so it does not NEED to be exactly like this):

```
results <- data.frame(c("T-A1-1", "T-A1-2", "T-A1-3", "T-A1-4"), c("num", "y/n; string; NAs; Dates", "y/n; NAs, num", "string; Dates; num"))
names(results) <- c("ID", "col")
  ID                     col
1 T-A1-1                     num
2 T-A1-2 y/n; string; NAs; Dates
3 T-A1-3           y/n; NAs, num
4 T-A1-4      string; Dates; num
```

I have been combing different forums for hints on how to affront this, but to no avail. I've been thinking about a nested `if` function, but with 83 columns it just got out of hand quick. Any ideas on how to tackle this would be greatly appreciated.

`R version 3.4.1`
`Winodws 7 64 bit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use two lists (the two coders) with elements corresponding to record ID. Then iterate over the lists to detect which columns are mismatched for a given record ID.

```
library(tidyverse)

# build the lists
df1_list <- split(df1, df1$ID)
df2_list <- split(df2, df1$ID) # using the same factor to split incase one level is not present in both

# a custom function to test two dfs with same ID
columns_mismatched <- function(df1, df2) {

    df <- bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% select(-Coder)
    matches <- map_lgl(df, ~ length(unique(.)) != 1) # logical test if the length of unique values is not equal to 1 (meaning the values are mismatched)
    mis_matches <- matches[matches == TRUE] # keep only mismatches

    # return a tibble or df for easy binding in next step
    return(tibble(bad_cols = names(mis_matches) %>% paste(collapse = ";")))
}

map2_dfr(df1_list, df2_list, # similar to mapply() then do.call(list, rbind)
     ~ columns_mismatched(., .y), .id = "ID") # . represents the elements from df1_list, .y the elemetns of df2_list

# A tibble: 4 x 2
      ID             bad_cols
   <chr>                <chr>
1 T-A1-1                  num
2 T-A1-2 y/n;string;NAs;Dates
3 T-A1-3          y/n;NAs;num
4 T-A1-4     string;Dates;num
```

Comment: Hello Nate, this is an interesting approach. I am analyzing the code in order to learn and improve. I am having a bit of a problem understanding this part of your code. `matches <- map_lgl(df, ~ length(unique(.)) != 1)`.
Especially how the formula `~ length(unique(.)) != 1)` plays into the code.
I also have the same problem when understanding: `map2_dfr(df1_list, df2_list,  ~ columns_mismatched(., .y), .id = "ID")`.

Comment: The `map` function is from `library(purrr)` and is very similar to `lapply` etc from base R. The `map_lgl` goes over each column in df and checks if the values are identical, if they matched the length of  `unique` will be 1 and return FALSE. The `map2_dfr` part goes through both lists applies the function `columns_mismatched` then binds the resulting list together as a tibble. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

Using dplyr spread, lag, gather and paste you can achieve it.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

results <- dfboth %>%
  gather(key, value, -ID, -Coder) %>%
  group_by(ID, key) %>%
  mutate(next.value = lead(value, order_by=Coder)) %>%
  filter(Coder == "AAA") %>%
  filter(value != next.value | ((is.na(value) + is.na(next.value)) ==1)) %>%
  select(ID, key) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(col = paste(key, collapse = ";")) %>%
  arrange(ID)


ID    col
T-A1-1  num         
T-A1-2  y/n;string;NAs;Dates            
T-A1-3  y/n;NAs;num         
T-A1-4  string;Dates;num
```

Comment: The `NAs` column is not properly handled with this solution.

Comment: @kelli-Jean taken care now

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution done by merging the data frames by the different coders:

```
temp = merge(dfboth[dfboth$Coder == "AAA",], dfboth[dfboth$Coder == "BBB",],
             by = "ID", all=TRUE)
# Get names of the columns that need to be checked for matches
cols_to_match = names(dfboth)[3:ncol(dfboth)]

# Convert NA to character to allow check of matching NA values
temp$NAs.x[is.na(temp$NAs.x)] = "<N/A>"
temp$NAs.y[is.na(temp$NAs.y)] = "<N/A>"


# Get matches, TRUE if match, FALSE if not match
results = data.frame(ID = temp$ID,
           temp[,c(paste0(cols_to_match,".x"))] == temp[,c(paste0(cols_to_match,".y"))])
names(results)[2:ncol(results)] = cols_to_match

# Column to indicate whether all fields match
results$all_match = apply(results[2:ncol(results)], 1, all)

results$col = apply(results[,2:6], 1, function(x){ paste0(cols_to_match[!unlist(x)], collapse="; ")})
```

Comment: the NAs aren't mismatched for ID T-A1-1

Comment: @NateDay Yes, the `NAs` column is not mismatched for ID T-A1-1. My solution shows that only the `num` column is a mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Just for variety, here's a `data.table` solution. The first result is in a form more useful for further processing than human reading. Although, it's still pretty readable.

*Edited: now considers `NA` as matching `NA`*

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dfboth)

dfboth[
  ,
  {
    is_different <- vapply(
      .SD,
      function(x) !identical(x[1], x[2]),
      logical(1)
    )
    list(mismatch = names(.SD)[is_different])
  },
  by = "ID"
][
  mismatch != "Coder"
]
#         ID mismatch
#  1: T-A1-1      num
#  2: T-A1-2      y/n
#  3: T-A1-2   string
#  4: T-A1-2      NAs
#  5: T-A1-2    Dates
#  6: T-A1-3      y/n
#  7: T-A1-3      NAs
#  8: T-A1-3      num
#  9: T-A1-4   string
# 10: T-A1-4    Dates
# 11: T-A1-4      num
```

If you need it in the condensed form, just add a little extra formatting code to the second subsetting.

```
dfboth[
  ,
  {
    is_different <- vapply(
      .SD,
      function(x) !identical(x[1], x[2]),
      logical(1)
    )
    list(mismatch = names(.SD)[is_different])
  },
  by = "ID"
][
  mismatch != "Coder",
  list(col = paste0(mismatch, collapse = "; ")),
  by = "ID"
]
#        ID                     col
# 1: T-A1-1                     num
# 2: T-A1-2 y/n; string; NAs; Dates
# 3: T-A1-3           y/n; NAs; num
# 4: T-A1-4      string; Dates; num
```

Comment: the NAs aren't mismatched for ID T-A1-1